# how i can i show my database address on google map with out lat and long?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i have static code for google map which i have grabbed from google map. its working fine but i want to get address dynamically from database.
here is static ifram code.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d212767.65777110323!2d72.89295287903074!3d33.56650389702338!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x38df948974419acb%3A0x984357e1632d30f!2sRawalpindi%2C+Pakistan!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1459177032691" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Maps JavaScript API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple), you can do:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

  function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {
        lat: <?php echo $lat; ?>, 
        lng: <?php echo $lng; ?>
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatLng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

And when loading the view,

```
$data['lat'] = your db value;
$data['lng'] = your db value;
$this->load->view("whatever_view", $data);
```

Additionally, if you want to draw that polygon, you'll need to read [polygon-arrays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays)